# Парсинг JSON массива golang

Tags: json, golang

Имеется такой json массив

```
    {
    "subscribers" : [
        {
            "email" : "somemail@gmail.com",
            "name" : "Maksim",
            "phone" : "80-77-524-2432"
        },
        {
            "email" : "someAnotherMail@gmail.com",
            "name" : "Sasha",
            "phone" : ""
        },
        {
            "email" : "someAnotherMail_1@gmail.com",
            "name" : "NoName",
            "phone" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Вот структура этого массива в golang

```
type WorkList struct {
    Subscribers []struct {
        Email string `json:"email"`
        Name  string `json:"name"`
        Phone string `json:"phone"`
    } `json:"subscribers"`
}
```

Это функция получающая элементы из json массива

```
func LoadSubscribers(filename string) (*WorkList, error) { //filename - путь до файла с json
    bytes, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return &WorkList{}, err
    }

    var c *WorkList
    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &c)
    if err != nil {
        return &WorkList{}, err
    }
    return c, nil
}
```

В main файле нужно пробежаться по элементам subscribers в цикле. Как это сделать?

Вот моя реализация, которая не работает:

```
sub, err := config.LoadSubscribers("subsctibers.json")
// Обращаясь к элементу sub.Email (например) Я не могу получить оттуда значение
```

Как получить корректное значение из элемента sub?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

1. Переписываем функцию, которая принимает json файл

```
func LoadSubscribers(filename string) (*WorkList, error) {
    bytes, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return &WorkList{[]struct {
            Email string "json:\"email\""
            Name  string "json:\"name\""
            Phone string "json:\"phone\""
        }{}}, err
    }

    var c *WorkList
    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &c)
    if err != nil {
        return &WorkList{[]struct {
            Email string "json:\"email\""
            Name  string "json:\"name\""
            Phone string "json:\"phone\""
        }{}}, err
    }
    return c, nil
}
```

Далее запускаем цикл который будет пробегаться по всем значениям в массиве. Он принимает 2 параметра: int и вашу структуру.

выглядеть это будет так:

```
for _, r := range sub.Subscribers {
   fmt.Println(r.Email, r.Name, r.Phone)
}

// Output будет таким, каким и ожидается :)
```